# If ElseIf for three Option Buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I can write the "If" "Else" statement when using 2 radio buttons, but when trying to convert this to an "ElseIf" statement with a 3rd button being added in the code doesn't work.

I have tried google and YouTube and solution topics here and I can't find the answer I am after.

```
If OPButton1.Value = True Then
    ws.Range("G" & emptyRow).Value = OPButton1.Caption
ElseIf 
    OPButton2.Value = True
    ws.Range("G" & emptyRow).Value = OPButton2.Caption
Else
    OPButton3.Value = True
    ws.Range("G" & emptyRow).Value = OPButton3.Caption

End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `Elseif` that counts like a new `IF...Then` and you were missing the `Then` part.

```
If OPButton1.Value = True Then
    ws.Range("G" & emptyRow).Value = OPButton1.Caption
ElseIf OPButton2.Value = True Then
    ws.Range("G" & emptyRow).Value = OPButton2.Caption
ElseIf OPButton3.Value = True Then
    ws.Range("G" & emptyRow).Value = OPButton3.Caption
Else
    'what do you want to do in this case?
End If
```

Try it

Comment: Perfect this one worked a treat. managed to just get the data into a spreadsheet so we can see the results based on the options picked from the buttons. and for the Else I added a line to log out N/A if nothing was selected.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just write three separate `IF` statements. Hardly the most elegant solution, but it'd work

OR

```
   If button1= true then,
   Do this,
   Else,
   If button2 = true then,
   Do this,
   Else,
   If button2 = true then,
   Do this,
   End if,
   End if,
   End if,
```

Sorry for the poor format, on mobile can't make it look like code. New line everywhere theres a comma

Comment: thanks for the help. I get what you mean it definitely helped out there.